# Correct way of using wp_get_attachment_image() in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm looking for the correct way of using wp_get_attachment_image().

The following code:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'type' => 'attachment',
        'category_name' => 'portfolio'
        );
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    print_r($attachments);
?>
```

Generates the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 54
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2010-06-22 00:32:46
            [post_date_gmt] => 2010-06-22 00:32:46
            [post_content] => <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Capture.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-55" title="Capture" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Capture-300x114.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="114" /></a> 
            [post_title] => Our Own Site
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => open
            [ping_status] => open
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => our-own-site
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2010-06-22 00:40:22
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2010-06-22 00:40:22
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://localhost/wordpress/?p=54
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => post
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )
)
```

The following, however, doesn't return anything.

```
<?php
    echo wp_get_attachment_image(54, array('300', '300'));
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You must give it an ID of an **attachment**  What you did wrong was the `$args` param - **there is no `type`** param, correct is `'post_type' => 'attachment'` :) because it defaults to Post (`post_type` is `post`), you were giving it an ID of some "post", not "attachment" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `wp_get_attachment_image` only gets an image that was uploaded to wordpress, it doesn't output an image in the content of the post.

You have to output the content of the post for your example image.

Like: `echo $attachments['post_content'];`

Comment: So Wordpress doesn't have an internal function to get an uploaded image at a specific size?

Comment: No, the function you gave is the correct one, but you need to pass it the idea of the attachment itself not a post.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. But it should still return the image with size nearest to the specified size, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, when loading attachments it will.

Comment: The above is an attachment, and it doesn't load it though. Could this be a bug?

Comment: Look at the post_type. It isn't an attachment.

Answer (score 15):

Actually, I don't think the accepted answer really answers the question.

Your problem is that you're passing in the *post id* (`54` in your example; typically `$post->ID` in WP parlance) to `wp_get_attachment_image()`.  As can be seen in the [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/), you're supposed to use the *attachment id* (see `$attachment_id` below):

```
wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size, $icon );
```

In other words, you've got to do something like this:

```
$image_attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');
```

Answer (score 4):

wp_get_attachment_image function can accept four values as you can see:

```
wp_get_attachment_image ( int $attachment_id, string|array $size = 'thumbnail', bool $icon = false, string|array $attr = '' )
```

So i always use:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), array('700', '600'), "", array( "class" => "img-responsive" ) );  ?>
```

Note: we can simply use **get_the_ID()** to pass id of active post. and here **700 is width** and **600 is height** of attachment image. we can also pass our class as **array( "class" => "img-responsive" )**